# I want the text that is input in TextArea in same format

Tags: html, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using TextArea of AntDesign, when I input, say, 2-3 paragraphs in it, and hit enter to display it in a row, but it displays everything in one paragraph. I want the exact formatting that I did while entering in the text area. How to do that?

I am simply using Text area -

```
  <TextArea
     rows={2}
     style={{ width: "100%" }}
     defaultValue={this.state.value}
     onClick={this.handleValue}
  />
```

and to display on right side-

```
  <div>{this.state.value}</div>
```

EXPECTED

```
Hey, how are you doing today? I am fine. i hope your are fine

do give me a call when you are free.

contact - 1234567890
```

WHAT I GET IN RESULT

```
Hey, how are you doing today? I am fine. i hope your are fine do give me a call when you are free. contact - 1234567890
```

Comment: its simply the TextArea that i am using...i have that added above @Peter

Comment: do you need any more help with this question? Please let me know or mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `pre` tag for displaying the content as entered.

I have created following example using `vanilla JS`. You can implement the same in `react`.

```html
<textarea id="tarea" rows="2" style="width: 100%" onclick="handleValue()">
</textarea>
<p id="display"></p>
<script>
  function handleValue() {
    var tarea = document.getElementById('tarea');
    var disp = document.getElementById('display');
    disp.innerHTML = '<pre>' + tarea.value + '</pre>';
  }
</script>
```

For eg:

`<pre>{this.state.value}</pre>`
should do the trick.

Hope this helps! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

So I don't think there is a simple way of doing so (even if the way of doing is not so hard).

What you'll have to do is get each line of the `TextArea`, you should be able to get this with something like this :

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("my-text-area");
var arrayOfLines = textArea.value.split("\n");
```

Source: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196954/how-to-read-line-by-line-of-a-text-area-html-tag`

Once you have `arrayOfLines`, you can output the text like it was typed in with a little `for()` loop.

Comment: Not the array, i have to change the backend too for that

Answer (score 1):

Provided below are two options for this task:

1. On keypress "Enter", append a newline char to the line.  When displaying the text, split on newline. [CodeSandbox example, listen for keycode](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-morning-oq3v7)

```
function App() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");

  function handleChange(e) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      setText(`${e.target.value}\n`);
    }
    setText(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <TextArea
        rows={4}
        value={text}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onPressEnter={handleChange}
      />

      {text.length > 0 && text.split("\n").map((l, i) => <p key={i}>{l}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

2. Use `pre` HTML tag.  This is simple, however it renders the text as a monospace font by default. [CodeSandbox example, using pre tag](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-kalam-4uyhm)

```
function App() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");

  function handleChange(e) {
    setText(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <TextArea
        rows={4}
        value={text}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onPressEnter={handleChange}
      />

      <pre>{text}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As AdityaSrivast said, you can use pre tags. But to wrap the text you should add below CSS.

```
<style>
     pre {
        overflow-x: auto;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
        white-space: -pre-wrap;
        white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
        word-wrap: break-word;
     }
  </style>
```

Otherwise, texts will show as one line.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the problem is in `style={{ width: "100%" }}`. Try to limit TextAreas width. For example: `style={{ width: "100px" }}`