# How to get data from textarea HTML tag in an array and then loop through it?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a webpage which would collect links from the user and simply open every link in a new tab. For collecting links I am using HTML's `<textarea>` tag with a submit button.

User is expected to give only one link for each line

```
https://google.com
https://stackoverflow.com
https://facebook.com
```

I would open links by sending each passing each URL through this function.

```js
function open(url) {
  var open= window.open(url, '_blank');
  open.focus();
}
```

But how exactly to run loop? How to get values from `textarea` in an array and then run a loop which would send value at every index to this function?

If you think this could be done in a better than other than this, feel free to add your method.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Comment: I have already added the function in JS code. The only thing in JS code would be this function and looping. And looping is what I can't figure out how to do. So only added this.

Comment: Not all top-rated answers are good: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11384018/661872 the second param which is using `_blank` is actually the [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) of the window and has nothing to do with the target prop. `window.open(url, url);` will work, but you wont want to focus on them all

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but am curious how did you found that I learnt about this function from top rated answer on SO, a quick google search?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read line by line of a text area HTML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196954/how-to-read-line-by-line-of-a-text-area-html-tag)

Comment: @Ankit how to properly loop, I got the answer about getting data from textarea but can't understand loop here.

Comment: I have added the answer, check and let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: @joi yes I believe he did a quick google search for the snippet you posted. When I did, I got the same top answer too.

Comment: The accepted answer to Ankit's proposed duplicate loops over the array in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you gave your textarea a unique identifier, this way we can get at its contents easily. i.e, `<textarea id="linksInput">...</textarea>`

Then we can do

`let links = document.getElementById("linksInput").value.split("\n");`

We get the value in the textarea and split it at every newline character ("\n"), getting our individual links in an array, with each element being a single line from the original textarea value. Now we can loop through the array `links`.

```
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    open(links[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id to the text field and use javascript to get the value of TextArea.

Since you are looking at multiple values separated by `"/n"`, you will have to split the text and loop over the result.

```js
function submitText() {
  var textVal = document.getElementById("txtarea").value;

  textVal = textVal.split('\n');

  if (textVal.length > 0) {
    for (const element of textVal) {
      console.log(element);
      window.open(element, "_blank");
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txtarea"></textarea>

<button type="button" onclick="submitText()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get your result.

**HTML**

```
<textarea id='links'>
</textarea>

<button id='trigger'> Get value </button>
```

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{

const ta = document.getElementById('links')
const button = document.getElementById('trigger')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
 const list = ta.value.split('\n')
 forEach(let i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
   window.open(list[0], "_blank");
  }
})
})
```