# Cannot split textarea on newline created from html entities

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, newline

I have a textarea that needs a default value including new lines so I used the technique employing HTML entities found from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8627926/34806)

```
<textarea rows=4 id="mytextarea">John,2&#13;&#10;Jane,3&#13;&#10;John,4&#13;&#10;Jane,5</textarea>
```

Then I have a button with launches a button for parsing the textarea and the first thing I want to accomplish is creating a `rows` array from the textarea value but this is where I am having problems.  There is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3802243/34806) that goes into the details of which browsers represent line breaks as \r\n and which as \n only and though this may not be strictly necessary in my case I still decided to try it:

```
var textAreaValue = document.getElementById("mytextarea").value;
textAreaValue = textAreaValue.replace(/\s/g, ""); //remove white space

var rows = textAreaValue.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").split("\n");
```

`rows` however is coming back as `["John,2Jane,3John,4Jane,5"]`.  So the split is having no effect; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: because the entities are still there inside the in-memory string. you're just seeing the RENDERED version of those entities. try splitting on `&#13;&#10;` instead. That or run the string through an entity->raw decode cycle first.

Comment: I am voting to close my own question (it wouldn't let me delete it) due to beercohol's answer which, though it solves my problem, also shows that it's a poor question that won't help others in the future.  So if you come along this in the future and are tempted to downvote the question, vote to close it instead ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The \s in your regex is removing the line breaks. Try commenting out that replacement and check your rows value again, it should then be as you expect!

```
function parseText() {
    var textAreaValue = document.getElementById("mytextarea").value;
    //textAreaValue = textAreaValue.replace(/\s/g, ""); //remove white space

    var rows = textAreaValue.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").split("\n");

    alert(rows);
}
```

See JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xs2619cn/1/

I changed your commas to full stops just to make the alert output clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `\n` and `\r`, so you can splite `&#13;` or `&#10;`.

```
var rows = textAreaValue.replace(/(&#[13|10];)+/g, "\n").split("\n");
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/rr1zvxko/

Comment: It's still an array length of 1: `John,2Jane,3John,4Jane,5`