# Get Text From Textarea, and Storing Each Line in a Separate Variable

Tags: javascript

I'd like to make a custom order form for my website which will allow customers to input a custom engraved message into a textarea. Customers can engrave a maximum of 3 lines.

I'd like to collect the text from the textarea, and separate each line into its own variable. For example, if the customer typed into the textarea:

```
Amy and John Smith
12/14/95
I'll always be by your side
```

Is it possible to store each line as its own variable? (In JavaScript)

```
var engravementLine1 = "Amy and John Smith";
var engravementLine2 = "12/14/95";
var engravementLine3 = "I/'ll always be by your side";
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. For example, you can use `Scanner` class with its `nextLine()` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parse a textarea in substrings based on line breaks in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800795/parse-a-textarea-in-substrings-based-on-line-breaks-in-javascript)

Comment: Then you can use [Unpacking array into separate variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3422458/215552)

Comment: You can do this easily with RegExp, but I would actually use three different `<input type='text' />`s instead, so you can do individual test on each line and produce a separate error corresponding to other failures you should also program in. Like how long can each line be? What can the text on the specific line contain? Make sure you do checks Server-side also, as that is really the end-all be-all to your site integrity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to keep a specific format I wouldn't recommend using textarea as users are known to input unpredictable things.

You can get each line of a `<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>` by using this code:

```
document.getElementById('mytextarea').value.split('\n');
```

This will give you something like this

> const resultArr = ["Amy and John Smith", "12/14/95", "I'll always be by your side"]

You can then use `resultArr` and map everything to your variables like so

```
var engravementLine1 = resultArr[0];
var engravementLine2 = resultArr[1];
var engravementLine3 = resultArr[2];
```

**Update:** Look at [parse a textarea in substrings based on line breaks in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800795/parse-a-textarea-in-substrings-based-on-line-breaks-in-javascript/3802243#3802243)

Comment: Great would appreciate an accepted answer and or upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the value of the input using `.split(/\n/)`, where `/\n/` is a regular expression for a line break.  So doing this:

```
const string = "
Amy and John Smith
12/14/95
I'll always be by your side
"

const splitUp = string.split(/\n/)
```

Will give you an array where each line is a new item in an array, which can then easily be assigned values.